# Running a container with a Docker bind-mount causes container to return Node version and exit

Tags: docker, filesystems, docker-volume

I am trying to attach a directory of static assets to my docker instance after it has been built. When I do something like this

```
docker run -it app /bin/bash
```

The container runs perfectly fine. However, if I do something like this:

```
docker run -it app -v "${PWD}/assets:/path/to/empty/directory" /bin/bash
```

This also reproduces it:

```
docker run -it node:12.18-alpine3.12 -v "${PWD}/assets:/path/to/empty/directory" /bin/bash
```

It spits out the version of Node `v12.18.4` I am using and immediately dies.  Where am I going wrong? I am using docker with wsl2 on windows 10. Is it due to filesystem incompatibility?

**edit:** whoops it's spitting out the node version and not the alpine version

Comment: Can we please see the Dockerfile and whatever scripts are running

Comment: Docker-specific options like `-v` need to come _before_ the image name `app`; otherwise they're taken as the command to run.  (I'd put a `COPY` command in the Dockerfile to include the assets in the image.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug my issue I tried running a bare-bones alpine container:

```
docker run -it alpine:3.12 -v "${PWD}/assets:/usr/app"  /bin/sh
```

Which gave a slightly more useful error message:

`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"-v\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.`

From this I realized that docker was trying to run `-v` as a starting command. I decided to change the order around, things started working.

**TL;DR** The `-v` argument and its corresponding parameter must be placed before the container name when performing a `docker run` command. i.e. the following works

```
docker run -it -v "${PWD}/assets:/usr/app" alpine:3.12 /bin/sh
```

but this doesn't:

```
docker run -it alpine:3.12 -v "${PWD}/assets:/usr/app"  /bin/sh
```